# Symfony2 Doctrine move millions of entries from one entity manager to another

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a db table with a lot of entries(about 2 million), I want to move out these data out from the system core database to other database using another entity manager. The data should be moved using a cron job, in the core db it should keeped the daily data and the data older than one day should be moved to the new db.

So I programmed that using one command, I tried to get the data in blocks of 1000 entries save them and clear the entity manager and it works well, but after 40-50k entries I get exceptions like:

```
  Allowed memory size of xyz bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in 

  vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Formatter/NormalizerFormatter.php on line 65
  vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Formatter/LineFormatter.php on line 71
  vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php on line 577
```

Is there any way to do that, avoiding these monolog errors?

Comment: Are you using the `--no-debug` and maybe `--env=prod` options with `php app/console` ?

Comment: try to `$em->flush()` and `$em->clear($entity)` below 40k entries, for example 20k entries.

Comment: Transferring millions of records using one php command?  Not going to happen regardless of what you try.  Your cron needs to kick off a master processor that in turn kicks off a php sub process which transfers maybe 10k records.  Upon completion of the sub process, the main processor will then kick off a new sub process.  Even this will probably be unreliable.  php is just not designed for huge batch processing.

Comment: @AdrienBrault, thank you using --no-debug I was able to process up to 100k entries but after that the process finishes.

Comment: @ihsan I do a em->flush and a em->clear after 1000 entries, and then I get the next entries.

Comment: @Cerad you are right, the tests have shown that I can up to 180k entries pro command call copy, the solution will be a SQL copy for the first time, and then a daily copy of the day data (80k entries)